# In gmail can I print all the emails under a label? 

Tags: gmail, printing

I have a filter and label setup that has automatically added the label 'receipt 2009' to all my online purchases - yey!

Now I need to print them all, is there an easy way besides opening every email?

Comment: Related: [In Gmail, what is the safest way to download, save & print all emails with a given label?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60144/354)

Answer (score 2):

Enable IMAP, configure a local email client for IMAP access, and print all the messages in that folder.

Comment: isn't that a mega chore ???

Comment: I guess it depends on the email client. Some let you highlight a bunch of messages and print them all at once.

Comment: It's easier than opening each message with that label and the only practical way to do it. Mozilla Thunderbird is stupid-easy to set up with Gmail.