# In Gmail, what is the safest way to download, save & print all emails with a given label?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Attempting to securely download all the emails with a given label in Gmail, save them to a single file, and print that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download all emails with a given tag  by retrieving a back up of your email account with [Google takeout](https://www.google.com/settings/takeout): you can select which labels you want to download.

The back up of your email account is a `.mbox`, that you can open using Thunderbird + [importexporttools addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/), [Windows MBox Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mbox-viewer/) (the latter didn't like my 1.4 GB .mbox file so might be some issues with large files), [SysTools MBOX Viewer](http://www.systoolsgroup.com/mbox-viewer.html) or any other mbox viewer.

Edit: (thanks [blunders](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/5723/blunders) for the info!) You can [print multiple emails in Thunderbird](http://realestate.about.com/od/softwareandservices/ss/email_manage_8.htm):

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, able to confirm that the above works; issue is your answer does not show how to print the files, say from Thunderbird directly to paper, or better yet to a PDF, that's then printable. Is there a reason you failed to answer that aspect of the question? Thanks!

Comment: Yes: I'm not sure which mbox viewer allow to print several emails at once :) (to paper or to pdf, doesn't matter, just install PDFCreator if it can only print to paper)

Comment: Selected as answer; okay, well it appears that [Thunderbird](http://realestate.about.com/od/softwareandservices/ss/email_manage_8.htm) supports this, and agree, the PDF aspect is just a matter of using [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). Thanks!