# Print emails from a specific person in Gmail

Tags: gmail, printing

I have emails from Mr. A in my Gmail account. Is there any way to print all emails from Mr. A without opening his email one by one?

Comment: [Relevant](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/60144/1512).

Answer (score 0):

- get this: **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pretty-print-gmail/gdanfldekhdgkbmdoeapbgbcpfglkflg)**
- restart browser
- go to **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox**
- search and select all emails you want to print
- press **<kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>P</kbd>**
- and print it